# Can't update or install anything. Ubuntu 3.11.0.14

Tags: updates

This is the result I get trying to get updates. Internet connection is fine, if I put the URL's in a browser, it gets to the address and downloads packages OK.. What is the fix for this error `Could not resolve hostname`?  Lots of these errors ocur, I am only allowed to post 2 links..

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for quinco: 

Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg                   
  Could not resolve 'hostname'
Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg                    
  Could not resolve 'hostname'
```

Comment: Can you post your `sources.list`?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on Linux Questions, turned out to be an entry in the line in a file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf/` called `01proxy`

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://"hostname":3142";
```

I commented out the line and now everything is OK