# Broken `apt-get update`

Tags: 14.04, apt

I have a problem, that when running `$sudo apt-get update`, it get's stuck with something like this:

> ```
> Ign https://apt.dockerproject.org ubuntu-trusty InRelease                      
> Ign https://download.docker.com trusty InRelease                               
> Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
>
> Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
>   Unable to connect to 10.11.55.xxx:3142:
> Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
>
> Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                     
>   Unable to connect to 10.11.55.xxx:3142:
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
>
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
>
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
>
> Err http://packages.cloud.google.com cloud-sdk-trusty InRelease
>
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
>   Unable to connect to 10.11.55.xxx:3142:
> Err http://packages.cloud.google.com cloud-sdk-trusty Release.gpg
>   Unable to connect to 10.11.55.xxx:3142:
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
>   Unable to connect to 10.11.55.xxx:3142:
> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
>   Unable to connect to 10.11.55.xxx:3142:
> ```

And it takes a really long time, to ultimately fail. I suspect is some network configuration (my IP used to be  10.11.55.YY, but moved to a different network).

I *noticed* the issue when trying to install docker, but I'm not really sure it had to do anything with this issue.

Any pointers on how to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you have configured `apt` to use a local proxy - see this similar question [Can't update or install anything. Ubuntu 3.11.0.14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/442688/cant-update-or-install-anything-ubuntu-3-11-0-14)

Comment: @steeldriver That was it!  just removed the line `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://10.11.55.xxx:3142"` from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90-apt-proxy.conf` and worked! Feel free to add as an answer if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with docker.

It turned out that APT had a proxy configured. Not sure how it got there, maybe IT placed it in the first place. When I moved to a different sub network, the proxy broke (since it wouldn't be reachable anymore).

The solution was to remove the following line from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90-apt-proxy.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://10.11.55.xxx:3142"
```

Thanks to @steeldriver for the pointers.